# urls not found after using .htaccess mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, url

i have a .htaccess file on my server and i am using mod_rewrite to hide the .php extension in the url.
so `http://www.mysite.com/home.php` becomes `http://www.mysite.com/home`

however i get a 404 error message saying the page was not found.
am i missing something, do i need to change my links to an absolute path? because even if a user   tries to type in `http://www.mysite.com/home` or `http://www.mysite.com/home.php` it still says the page was not found.

here's whats in my htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

Comment: Basically you want to remove your .php extension from your file names?

Comment: i want the users browser url to not show the .php at the end of the file names, so i have contact_us.php on my server, if a user clicks the link contact us their url will show http://www.mysite.com/contact_us (so no .php extension is shown) but at the moment my links can not be found

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# turn on the mod_rewrite engine

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
# redirect to the php script with the requested filename
```

Try the example I have posted. This should work to remove your PHP Extension

Comment: can i leave my links alone i.e. they look like this at the moment: <a href="home.php"> or do i need to change them to <a href="home">

Comment: i tried this but the .php at the end of the file is still shown in the url

Comment: You can leave this, but with the anchor references the user will be displayed with the .php extension due to you physically referring the user to this page; No errors will be provided if directing to .php or home

Comment: @JamesPale you are still being shown the .php because using .htaccess does not make automatic changes directly to the URL; if you navigate to http://www.mywebsite.com/index   you will be presented with your index page, if you wish to manipulate the clients URL, you will need to perform some server sided scripting to re-direct silently